# jsonobject IllegalAccessException can not access a member of class java.util.HashMap with modifiers "private"

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I am getting the following error while creating a JSONObject:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.json.JSONObject can not access a member of class java.util.HashMap with modifiers "private"
```

The DTO has 3 properties:

```
private list aList = new ArrayList();
private Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>> aMapOfMaps = new HashMap<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>>();
private Map<String, BigDecimal> aMap = new HashMapMap<String, BigDecimal>();
```

The error is thrown while creating a JSON object at,
`obj = new JSONObject(object);`

where object is the DTO object.
Not sure what am I doing wrong here or missing something. I would really appreciate any pointers to the soln.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem (assuming your issue is unrelated to the "HashMapMap" typo). It seems to be related to conflicts in dependencies. I'm still trying to get to the bottom of it...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your code won't compile at all, change it to :

```
private List aList = new ArrayList();
private Map<String, Map<String, BigDecimal>> aMapOfMaps = new HashMap<String, 
  Map<String,BigDecimal>>();
private Map<String, BigDecimal> aMap = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
```

Secondly, I have experienced these strange problems with `org.json`, if possible use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).